# Border not showing up in table

Tags: html, css

I have a css code, "border-top" is not displaying correctly. I've done everything correctly but I just don't see the problem.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3vnWh/1/

Code:

```
div.topb { 
border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have and open { and selector:

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/3vnWh/5/)**

```
/* optional div height ,width, color */
{   /*this is missing*/
width:400px;
height:200px;
background-color:#ffffff;
font-size:28px;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
table.topb
```

instead of

```
div.topb
```

Answer (score 0):

The section immediately before `div.topb` has no opening brackets or labels. If you comment this section out or give it the appropriate opening brackets, your border-top will display properly. Your section looks like this and can be fixed by adding a { before the width line:

```
/* optional div height ,width, color */
width:400px;
height:200px;
background-color:#ffffff;
font-size:28px;
color:#ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use any of the following

```
   .topb

   { 
      border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc; 
   }
```

**OR**

```
   table 
   { 
       border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc; 
    }
```

**OR**

```
   table.topb 
  { 
   border-top: 1px solid #dcdcdc; 
   }
```